# Drag & Drop on multiple objects and targets

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have several balls each that are associated to a fruit. I want it so that when someone drags the ball onto the associated fruit it will call an action (In this case trace 'hit fruit') if not then do something else. At the moment it's not detecting this.

I've found that I can add an even listener to the stage to detect when this is done, but the problem is I have multiple balls, each with multiple fruits. Can anyone tell me how I go about doing this.

I am from a PHP/Javascript background and am just a beginner when it comes to AS3

```
ball1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
ball1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);


function mouseUpHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
   var obj = e.target;

   if (e.target.hitTestObject("fruit1")) {
    trace('hit fruit1');
   } else {

   trace('Not hit fruit');
   } 

   obj.stopDrag();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array to store all of the fruit and use a loop to test whichever ball is being dragged and dropped:

```
var fruitArray:Array = new Array();
fruitArray.push(fruit1);
fruitArray.push(fruit2);
fruitArray.push(fruit3);

function onMouseUp(e:MouseEvent) : void
{
  for(var j=0; j<fruitArray.length; j++) { // Every piece of fruit is tested..
        if(e.target.hitTestObject(fruitArray[j])) { // ..against the ball being dragged
          trace("hit fruit:", fruitArray[j]);
        }
  }
}
```

You would need to use a similar for loop system to add the event listeners to the balls to begin with, and you can play with splitting the fruits into smaller arrays of different types, and only checking a ball against a particular fruit array.

Comment: You wouldn't need two four loops if only one ball was being dragged at a time.  That way you just check against the Active ball and reduce the computation on the callback.

Comment: Hah absolutely correct, don't know how I missed that one. On `MOUSE_UP` you need only check the ball currently being dragged with the fruit array - have updated the answer to reflect this.